# Is tool safety on-topic?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/78/is-this-table-saw-lathe-jig-safe), the first comment was asking whether tool safety is on-topic. I would think that it would be, as woodworkers without fingers aren't very efficient or effective.

Comment: As question **and** comment OP, I'd like to establish why I asked if it was on-topic: Obviously at least one person considered this jig "safe enough" to build and use it, introducing a bit of subjectivity to the nature of its safety.

Comment: I believe that question asking for the (tips / guide) of using safely some tools to work with wood should be on-topic.

Comment: I was hoping the answers would be objective, which BrownRedHawk did a good job of providing a concrete answer of "it's unsafe because X".

Answer (score 4):

I personally think they should be on topic for just the reason you have mentioned. I don't think there will be very many of these, though, as many of them will have large overlap, which could probably be closed as a duplicate once a large enough base of the answers come to fruition. Ultimately, though, it's all in how you utilize a tool whether it's safe or not. If you use the tool as it's meant to be used, you can be pretty sure it's safe (common sense, which it appears is lacking in some cases). It's when you get outside of those bounds where it becomes unsafe. Doesn't mean people aren't going to use it that way, but hopefully they'll ask the question first and not end up as a [Darwin Award Winner](http://www.darwinawards.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with previous answers, and would add that safety should be a top priority on this site, and allowing questions around that subject seems like a clear requirement for that to be the case.

If we are seen flagging safety questions as "off-topic" then when the general public sees those questions as flagged, it will decrease the respect they have for this community (at least, it would diminish my respect for this community).

I vote on topic as well.

Answer (score 1):

I vote 'on topic'. Any discussion of woodworking involves discussing tool use and that includes tool safety. I'm all for preserving my ability to count to 10 :)

Answer (score 1):

Tool safety in my opinion is very important, most of the tools we use can be very dangerous if not used properly.  I would think that adding in special care should be a good idea in many answers, even if it isn't asked for.